# Why does this python statement got stuck?

Tags: python, tuples, range, exponent

Have anyone ever experienced this statement? The following code looks work well, but it makes my laptop get stuck when the exponent reaches 9 or above.

```py
ordered_tuple = tuple(range(10**9))
```

Every time I run this statement, my laptop slows down, got stuck taking up 100% of RAM usage.
I searched for the reason why this happened, but there was no suitable answer.

Please help me understand why this code makes computers busy.
Thanks in advance.

I tried with different exponent between [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10].
1-8 works fairly well as I expected.

```py
ordered_tuple = tuple(range(10**1))
ordered_tuple = tuple(range(10**2))
ordered_tuple = tuple(range(10**3))
ordered_tuple = tuple(range(10**4))
ordered_tuple = tuple(range(10**5))
ordered_tuple = tuple(range(10**6))
ordered_tuple = tuple(range(10**7))
ordered_tuple = tuple(range(10**8))
```

whereas 9, 10 doesn't work.

Comment: Allocating and initializing a billion numbers takes time.

Comment: The failing case would require something like 40 gigabytes of memory, for all of the int objects plus the tuple itself.  Does your computer have 40GB of RAM?

Comment: One Python integer is 32 bits, so a tuple of 10^9 elements is about 30GB in size. I think it's no wonder why your laptop freezes.

Comment: Is this a joke question? It's a little early for Apr 1

Comment: A `tuple` isn't a zero-cost data structure. If you're asking for billions of entries, you're going to need billions of bytes of memory.

Comment: [This classic video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0fKBhvDjuy0) shows how small changes in an exponent corresponds to huge changes in size.

Comment: Perhaps there is a way to get what you seek a different way. What is the motivation for the creation of a billion element tuple?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`10**9` is 10 times as big as `10**8`. `10**10` is 100 times as big as `10**8`. Likely your computer just does not have enough RAM to hold all these numbers.

PS: Not sure how long is a Python int, if it is 4-byte long, then `10**9` of them is 4 GB, but then `10**10` does not fit in 4-byte long int and needs more. If it is 8-byte long, then `10**9` is 8 GB and `10**10` is 80 GB.